# For Physical Security, what constitutes as a "Campus"?

Tags: physical-security

In regards to physical security what constitutes a "Campus"? Is there a definition somewhere which describes what makes up a campus appose to standard set office buildings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Campus is one of those nebulous terms like 'site' that has no standard definition. *In general* a campus is a group of buildings sharing a common parcel (or contiguous parcels) of land. The 15th floor of a 60 floor building may be the 'campus' of a company, whereas the Microsoft campus in Redmond, Washington has many buildings on it.

Exceptions occur when there are small offices *near* a major campus, those may be considered their own campus, or part of the main one. Again continuing with Microsoft, they have several large offices in downtown Bellevue, Washington. Is that a different campus, or the same? I don't know.

Comment: Thank you.
So in our case, our office is located on one floor of a building.  There are three buildings connected by a common garage and hallways.  Would these buildings with parking lot, etc. be considered a 'Campus'?

Comment: I'll use my favorite answer ever.  "It Depends."  This is the kind of question I ask the relevant auditor for clarification on.

Comment: @Brettski Very possibly. Microsoft would, though if that's your entire company maybe not you. @packs has the right idea.